# Set default result from WEKA classification

Tags: weka, default-value

Is it possible to set default result value from WEKA classification?
I would like to set default value when system can't classify data.

For example, 
This is my dataset that I would like to classifier emotion from text sentence.

```
I love it: happy
I hate it: sad
Today is Monday: normal
I like them: happy
...
```

So when I get input like "This is a book", "A cat in the hat" ;that they are not in training set; I wonder system to return default classify result to "normal" like

```
I love it: happy
I like them: happy
A cat in a hat: normal (by default)
This is a book: normal (by default)
```

Please tell me how to set it.

** Now I test on classifier on meta-classifier (choose J48 and SVM as classifier)

Comment: I am not quite sure: if you are saying "classify those instances in the test set with label X that were not seen in the training set", then are you not letting your classifier to have "intentional" overfitting?

Comment: Thank you for your attention.
Sorry for unclear explaining. I will give clear example,
I want to classifier "DAY" and "REJECT"
If I send "Sunday", "Monday".....,"Saturday" , I want to get result "DAY". 
In another hands, if get another text, I want WEKA returns "Rejcet".

Do you know how to set WEKA for this case.